# Bundling same react-native source code doesn't work on different machine

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm creating a project using create-react-native-app.

It's currently on my home laptop but when I clone it onto my work laptop and run 'npm run ios' or 'android', it simply wont bundle.

I assumed it was because the directories were different etc

/Users/jonpucxyz/Documents/code/react-native...
versus
/Users/jonathan/Documents/code/react-native...

so I replaced the strings with the right directory paths from my work laptop.

It still comes up with errors and wont bundle.

[image]

[image]

This is kind of a pain as I hope to be able to work on the project both at home and at work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance have a different OS system or architecture in both machines? Like a Windows and a Linux or a Linux and a Mac?

Some libraries need specific compiled packages like crypto.

Try deleting the node_modules folder, deleting npm cache with "npm --reset-cache" and then a "npm install" for a fresh install.

Comment: Nope same OS system. 

I will try that. Thanks.